# Multi-seat linux and windows computer

Tags: windows, multiseat, multi-user, multisystem

i know there are programs to run lots of Linux users at the same time, and the same for windows, but i was wondering if there was a way to run windows and Linux at the same time for multiple different users. For example, you turn on a monitor connected to the main pc and can choose an operating system that you want to use, for example, ubuntu, and then a different person comes along and selects that they want to use windows?

edit: I don't want to use a VM, something similar to [Aster](https://www.ibik.ru/) would be prefered.

Comment: Is there a way to do this more using something like aster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without one or both OS in a Virtual Machine, the answer is a hard 'No'.

Each operating system requires full control of the CPU, memory, filesystem, etc. Two operating systems cannot control the same hardware simultaneously. The process of switching between operating systems involves a reboot.

Comment: thanks, is there s way to link in some extra computers and use their hardware as well, in a sort of super computer and you choose at the bios?

Comment: ok thanks i will