# Is there a way to link computers and use their hardware to run windows and linux at the same for multi-seat?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, multiseat, multisystem

This is actually from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352409/multi-seat-linux-and-windows-computer/1352414#1352414), but apparently you have to have a separate hardware array to run these two operating systems multi-seat. so i was wondering if you could have multiple computers connected some way and then use windows and Linux, perhaps selecting them at a sort of bios at the same time.

edit: e.g. you turn on a monitor connected to the main pc and can choose an operating system that you want to use, for example, ubuntu, and then a different person comes along and selects that they want to use windows?

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you’re trying to do. Are you hoping to run both OSes simultaneously? Is the goal to allow multiple people to RDP into the machine and choose an OS to work within?

Comment: I would like to have both OSes running at the same time, each with multiple users connected. It would be with multiple users at the same time, on several monitors.

Comment: [The answer you received an hour ago](https://askubuntu.com/a/1352414/1222991) still stands. You will need to use virtual machines to accomplish this, as one set of hardware cannot run multiple OSes simultaneously on bare metal. You can accomplish your goal using VirtualBox, VMware, HyperVisor, and a number of other well-supported virtualization engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Thin Clients + Remote Desktop Pool

From latest comment it seems you want
Many sets of peripherals , and 2(+) computers.
Where at least one computer runs linux, and one runs windows.
And the users connect them, sometimes with multiple users concurrently connected to the same machine

A way this can be accomplished is with a [thin-client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client).
You set up ultracheap computers (e.g. Raspberry Pi) for each set of peripherals.
They run something line the [ThinStation OS](https://thinstation.github.io/thinstation/).
Which as it's log-in screen lets you select what "real" computer you would like to connect to.
It then connects either to your linux computer via e.g. SSH with X11 Forwarding,
or to your Windows computer via RDP.
When yo

You'll need to have up the other end of  SSH and RDP  on the "real" computers, and may need a suitable license for multiple concurrent users on windows (I am not sure these days).

I have seen this working years ago, it can be pretty smooth.

Comment: Would something like that work with cameras and things like that. So you could do a voice call from the thinclient which is connected to an RDP server, and it would work as normal, everyone can see you, hear you ect?

Comment: Yes, at least in theory. I have never tried it but RDP supports forwarding webcams and microphones etc

Answer (score 0):

> i was wondering if you could have multiple computers connected some way and then use windows and Linux

It sounds like you are wanting a [KVM Switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch).

As I understand it you are talking about 1 monitor, 1 keyboard, 1 mouse etc,
but two computers (motherboard, CPU etc).
where one computer runs linux and the other windows.
And you want to switch between them.

A KVM switch is a physical device that you connect multiple computers,
and 1 set of peripherals to.
Then you press a button to change which computer the peripherals are connected to.

Comment: Sort of, but there would be multiple users connected to each OS and doing stuff. Perhaps I could use a separate multi-seat program for each computer, and then you choose the computer with KVM and the user with multi-seat?

Comment: Ah, I think you want a collection of thin clients, and another pool of remote desktop servers.
I have seen this done.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at that.